# Fetch backbone model parent relation without making additional request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have models like this:

```
window.Client = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/Client',
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany,
            key: 'appointments',
            relatedModel: 'Appointment',
            autoFetch:true,
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'client',
                keySource: 'client_id',
                includeInJSON: 'id',
                autoFetch:true,
            }
        }
    ]
}); 
window.Appointment = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/Appointment',
});
```

JSON in `'/api/Appointment'` response contains `client` object data, so when I am fetching single appointment, I expect it to contain related `Client` object, but it doesn't.

```
var a= new Appointment({id:1});
a.fetch();
a.get('client');//null
a.fetchRelated('client')//this will make another request and get data that browser already have
```

Is it possible to make backbone-relational automatically set up parent relation?

Answer (score 0):

fetch() is an asynchronous method, it might take some time for it to finish. Try waiting for a.fetch to complete before checking if client is initialized:

```
a.fetch({
    success: function () {
       console.log(a.get('client'));
    }
});
```

In addition, you say the json returned by /api/Appointment contains the client data. If this is the case, you shouln't set autoFetch to true as an additional fetch is not required.